# Dispenser Counters in XFS is very different from the Counters maintained by the application

Tags: xfs, cen-xfs

I was trying to build an application which will monitor activities on Peripheral through XFS.

Whenever there is a change in Cash Units, application receives CASHUNITINFO_CHANGED event.
Based on which I fetch the Cash Unit Information using CASHUNITINFO command.

I find that the Dispenser XFS API does not give me the correct counter in one of the NCR ATM. I have tested the same code in both Diebold and Wincor and I am getting correct counter values.

I am using the WFS_INF_CDM_CASH_UNIT_INFO command to fetch ulInitialCount, ulCount, ulRejectCount, ulDispensedCount, ulPresentedCount for each logical cash unit.

For example, this is what I see in XFS...

[FROM XFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgZH.gif)

but in ATM cash counter admin screen, the counters is different as shown below.

[FROM ATM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6AUV.gif)

Thanks,
Srivathsan

Comment: @Hans Passant: Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Are you sure the data shown is extracted in the same way? It could be that data shown in the ATM (I assume it will be the ATM application), does not come from XFS.

Comment: @SuperG280:  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @SuperG280:  Thanks for you response. No I'm not sure the data were extracted the same way but the ATM vendor claims they do use XFS to extract data.

Is there any way to find it?

Apart from this I can able to see multiple Service Providers for single dispenser in the registry however ATM has only one dispenser.

Can a multiple Service Provider co-exists in the same host to access one single device at a time ?

Comment: It is usual for the manufacturer to install all the SPIs that make up a version of its platform, even though the devices are not physically in the ATM. If you don't execute the WFSOpen function for that logical name (SPI), it is still installed software that never runs. In certain ATM applications, the counters are carried by the host. When a money load is made, the host is informed. In each dispensing order the host sends the banknote mix and updates its counters. That's why I asked you if the counters shown by the application were from XFS (CASH_UNIT_INFO).